# Using ConvLSTM2d followed by CNN with Keras, Tensorflow 2.0?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, conv-neural-network

So i am trying to train a model which is combination of CLSTM and CNN. If i use the filter size of 40  with CLSTM i have to use the same size with CNN and i can't seem to change the filter size for CNN and also i can't use MAXPOOLING layer as well? Can anyone let me know how can i change the filter size and add maxpooling layer in my model
This code is running

```
model = models.Sequential()
model.add(layers.ConvLSTM2D(filters=32, kernel_size=(3, 3),
                                data_format='channels_last', 
                                input_shape=(None, 28, 28, 1), padding='same',
                                return_sequences=True))
model.add(layers.BatchNormalization())
model.add(layers.AveragePooling3D((1, 28, 28)))

model.add(layers.TimeDistributed((layers.Conv2D(32, (3,3), padding = "same",
                                             activation='relu'))))
model.add(layers.TimeDistributed((layers.Conv2D(32, (3,3), padding = "same",
                                                activation='relu')))) 
model.add(layers.Reshape((-1, 32)))

model.add(layers.Dense(1, activation='linear'))
model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='mean_squared_error', metrics=['mae'])   
model.summary()
```

I want to have my model like below

```
model.add(layers.ConvLSTM2D(filters=40, kernel_size=(3, 3),
                                data_format='channels_last', 
                                input_shape=(None, 28, 28, 1), padding='same',
                                return_sequences=True))
model.add(layers.BatchNormalization())

model.add(layers.TimeDistributed((layers.Conv2D(32, (3,3), padding = "same",
                                             activation='relu'))))
model.add(layers.TimeDistributed(layers.MaxPooling2D((2, 2))))

model.add(layers.TimeDistributed((layers.Conv2D(64, (3,3), padding = "same",
                                             activation='relu'))))
model.add(layers.TimeDistributed(layers.MaxPooling2D((2, 2))))

model.add(layers.TimeDistributed((layers.Conv2D(128, (3,3), padding = "same",
                                             activation='relu'))))
model.add(layers.TimeDistributed(layers.MaxPooling2D((2, 2))))

model.add(layers.Reshape((-1, 128)))
model.add(layers.Dense(1, activation='linear'))
model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='mean_squared_error', metrics=['mae'])   
model.summary()
```

I get error with the above model.

**ValueError: Negative dimension size caused by subtracting 2 from 1 for 'time_distributed_1/max_pooling2d/MaxPool' (op: 'MaxPool') with input shapes:**

**EDIT:1**

max_pooling error removed by adding padding=same

```
model.add(layers.ConvLSTM2D(filters=40, kernel_size=(3, 3),
                                data_format='channels_last', 
                                input_shape=(None, 28, 28, 1), padding='same',
                                return_sequences=True))
model.add(layers.BatchNormalization())

model.add(layers.TimeDistributed((layers.Conv2D(32, (3,3), padding = "same",
                                             activation='relu'))))
model.add(layers.TimeDistributed(layers.MaxPooling2D((2, 2), padding = "same")))

model.add(layers.TimeDistributed((layers.Conv2D(64, (3,3), padding = "same",
                                             activation='relu'))))
model.add(layers.TimeDistributed(layers.MaxPooling2D((2, 2), padding = "same")))

model.add(layers.TimeDistributed((layers.Conv2D(128, (3,3), padding = "same",
                                             activation='relu'))))
model.add(layers.TimeDistributed(layers.MaxPooling2D((2, 2), padding = "same")))

model.add(layers.Reshape((-1, 128)))
model.add(layers.Dense(1, activation='linear'))
model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='mean_squared_error', metrics=['mae'])   
model.summary()
```

Now the error is

*ValueError: Dimensions must be equal, but are 5120 and 10 for 'loss/dense_9_loss/SquaredDifference' (op: 'SquaredDifference') with input shapes: [10,5120,1], [10,10,1].*

Comment: why there is an average pooling 3d layer ? instead of 2d ?

Comment: This model doesn't really make sense. You are using global average pooling so the spatial dimensions will be reduced to 1 (i.e. the output is 1x1 pixels). What's the point of doing further convolution/pooling on there? For the record, the error can be fixed by including `padding="same"` in the max pooling layers, but the model still makes no sense, unless I am fundamentally misunderstanding something

Comment: Ok... the model i need doesn't involve _AveragePooling3D()_ . I edited out that line. The point is to use **CNN after CLSTM**  and even if i add **padding=same** only maxpooling layer gets right. i still get the dimensionality error. Even instead of reshaping before dense layer i do _Flatten()_

Comment: New Error is : _ValueError: Dimensions must be equal, but are 5120 and 10 for 'loss/dense_6_loss/SquaredDifference' (op: 'SquaredDifference') with input shapes: [10,5120,1], [10,10,1]._

Comment: can you share the model summary along with shapes of x_train and y_train, i tried your edited code, i'm not getting any error.

Comment: @SachinPrasadHS did you use pooling after ConvLSTM2D